# MySql string search as Date using LIKE

Tags: mysql

I am managing a system designed 10 years ago for booking lessons.

The data structure saves the `startTime` as a string in the format `YYYYmmDDHHMM` and same format as lesson `endTime`.

How can I run a query which can get me all the lessons booked at `HHMM` (0930 or 1630) in future only?

The lesson may be an hour long and booked from `09:00` to `10:00`, so If I put the search time as `09:30` this lesson should be returned as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean YYYYmmDDHHMM - e.g. 20181030181818 for 6pm, 18 minutes on October 30th of this year?

Comment: What do you mean by booked at HHII (0930 or 1630)?

Comment: @Owen means all the lessons booked at 09:30 ? Get the list of all booked lesson at a certain time to check the availability.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `STR_TO_DATE` and `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(startTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i') > CURDATE() AND 
      (RIGHT(startTime, 4) = '0930' OR RIGHT(startTime, 4) = '1630')
```

**Update**

To look for lessons which may overlap the desired time (e.g. a lesson that goes from 9am to 10am) is a little more complicated. Basically we also need to get the `time` part of the value and check for it surrounding 9:30 or 16:30 e.g.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(startTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i') > CURDATE() AND 
      ('09:30' BETWEEN TIME(STR_TO_DATE(startTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')) AND TIME(STR_TO_DATE(endTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')) OR
       '16:30' BETWEEN TIME(STR_TO_DATE(startTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')) AND TIME(STR_TO_DATE(endTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')))
```

Comment: Does this solve the `BETWEEN` problem? The lesson may be an hour long and booked from `09:00` to `10:00`, so If I put the search time as `09:30` this lesson should be returned as well.

Comment: @MikeRoss sorry that requirement wasn't obvious from your question.  Let me get back to you

Comment: If I have an entry with `endTime` at `09:30` and run the query, that row is returned. So if the lesson is finishing at `09:30` so another lesson can be booked with `startTime` as `09:30`. Can you help solve that?

Comment: @MikeRoss you would need to change the condition to `startTime <= '09:30' AND endTime > '09:30'` (still keeping the `TIME(STR_TO_DATE(..., '%Y%m%d%H%i'))` around the `startTime` and `endTime` variables) and the same for `'16:30'`

Comment: @MikeRoss did this not help?